# How to rearrange multiple regression equation to solve for an independent in excel

Tags: statistics

Is there a way to solve this equation for $F_2$?  I am using excel to do this if that matters. Thanks for any help.

$Y=B_2+B_3F_2+B_4G_2+B_5H_2+B_6I_2+B_7J_2+B_8K_2$

Y=INTERCEPT+B1*X1+B2*X2+B3*X3+B4+X4+B5*X5+B6*X6

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you had initially $N$ data points $(F_i,G_i,H_i,I_i,J_i,K_i,Y_i)$ based on which you established a multilinear regression $$Y=B_2+B_3F+B_4G+B_5H+B_6I+B_7J+B_8K$$ and now, you want to extract $F$ from it. As you see, $F$ is a function of all other variables. Then, what I should do is to run another regression writing $$F=A_2+A_3Y+A_4G+A_5H+A_6I+A_7J+A_8K$$ based on the same data points.

Comment: How would this translate into excel? D2=B2+B3F+B4G+B5H+B6I+B7J+B8K, solving for F? I replaced Y with D2. Is A the intercept? How would your formula look in excel? I tried using the intercept everywhere you put an A and the answer it returns is the y value from the original equation.

Comment: It is the same problem since you performed the first regression using Excel. In the first case $(F_i,G_i,H_i,I_i,J_i,K_i)$ were the independent variables and $(Y_i)$ the dependent variable. So, now, perform another regression with $(Y_i,G_i,H_i,I_i,J_i,K_i)$ as independent variables and  $(F_i)$ the dependent variable.

Comment: Yes it is the same problem. I ran another regression using y as independent variable and f as the dependent variable and the results were not good. In your reply are the A Coefficients the same as in the first case or are they new coefficients from the new regression? If they are from the new regression, then I have to find another way because the regression was no good.

Comment: Coefficients $B_i$ were those you obtained from the first regression. Coefficients $A_i$ will be generated from the second regression.

Comment: When I ran the new regression, the results were terrible. It will not work. Is there a way to extend the equation for linear regression Y=A+BX, solving for X: X=(Y-A)/B. Is there a way to use this with the multiple regression equation?

Comment: I apologize ! My comment is probably the most stupid I ever made !